# Take value from two select option values

Tags: jquery, html

I have two select option tag div's , where I have to select value of only one select option tag.

If value of second select option is not available then I want value of first select option means second select must get avoid and if value of second select is available then I want only second select value means this time I have to ignore first select option value because second one is important.

Problem is I am not able to get value of first select if second select is not available.

HTML

```
               <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
            <p for="select_drug">Select Drug</p>
            <select name="select_drug1" id="select_drug1" class="form-control " required="required">
                    <option value="100"></option>
                    <option value="105"></option>
                    <option value="106"></option>
                    <option value="107"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="anothersubcategory" class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
            <p for="selectsub">Select Drug Sub-Category</p>
            <select style="width:100%;" name="selectsub" id="selectsub" class="form-control ">
                    <option value="0">Choose One</option>
                    <option value="80"></option>
                    <option value="82"></option>
                    <option value="85"></option>
                    <option value="86"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

JS

```
function editDrug() {
  var value = $('#select_drug1').val();
  var svalue = $('#selectsub').val();
  if (svalue == '' || svalue == '0' || svalue == 'null') {
    var id = svalue;
  } else {  
    var id = value;  
  }        
  alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I tried reading it three times and had no idea what you are saying/asking!

Comment: If i'm understanding this correctly, he wants the second select's value if it is set.  If it is not set, he wants the first selects value.  The second select takes precedence over the first select.

Comment: @Taplar : Yes you are right buddy can you please help me for this??

Comment: @Taplar see now

Comment: what do you mean by "available"?

Comment: `$('#selectsub').val() || $('#select_drug1').val()`

Comment: @RickHitchcock `"0" || "38"` would return 0.  Non-empty strings are truthy, even if they are zero.

Comment: @Taplar, good point.  `+$('#selectsub').val() || $('#select_drug1').val()` should do the trick.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Can you please explain me what is your logic??

Comment: @Taplar: I am getting null for first dropdown even if value is set.

Comment: `x || y` evaluates to `x` if `x` is truthy; otherwise it evaluates to `y`.  Prepending a plus sign changes a string to a number (if possible).  I didn't post as an answer, because it doesn't show the problem with your code, which other answers succesfully do.

Comment: @SagarGopale compare my answer below to what you have.  you shouldn't be getting null

Answer (score 3):

See the comments in the code for information about what each step is doing.

```js
var $selectDrug = $('#select_drug1');
var $selectSub = $('#selectsub');

//bind on the change of the selects, just to see the computed value
$selectDrug.add($selectSub).on('change', function () {
  //get the first value
  var value = $selectDrug.val();
  
  //the "not selected" value is 0, so if it is zero, ignore it
  if ($selectSub.val() !== '0') {
    value = $selectSub.val();
  }
  
  //print out the value
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
  <p for="select_drug">Select Drug</p>
  <select name="select_drug1" id="select_drug1" class="form-control " required="required">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="105">105</option>
    <option value="106">106</option>
    <option value="107">107</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="anothersubcategory" class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
  <p for="selectsub">Select Drug Sub-Category</p>
  <select style="width:100%;" name="selectsub" id="selectsub" class="form-control ">
    <option value="0">Choose One</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="82">82</option>
    <option value="85">85</option>
    <option value="86">86</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: No explanation at all? ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  hey, I left step by step comments, ^_^

Comment: Haha.. .Sorry to be blind like this. As I may not be the only one, just add «See comments within code.» before the snippet.  And +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just reversed the `if` condition's logic...

```js
$("select").on("change",function(){
  var value = $('#select_drug1').val();
  var svalue = $('#selectsub').val();
  if (svalue == '' || svalue == '0' || svalue == 'null') {
    var id = value;
  } else {  
    var id = svalue;  
  }        
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
  <p for="select_drug">Select Drug</p>
  <select name="select_drug1" id="select_drug1" class="form-control " required="required">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="105">105</option>
    <option value="106">106</option>
    <option value="107">107</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="anothersubcategory" class="form-group col-lg-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
  <p for="selectsub">Select Drug Sub-Category</p>
  <select style="width:100%;" name="selectsub" id="selectsub" class="form-control ">
    <option value="0">Choose One</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="82">82</option>
    <option value="85">85</option>
    <option value="86">86</option>
  </select>
</div>
```